# "npm run dev" works, but "next dev" does not

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, next.js

I'm trying Next for the first time (with `npx create-next-app`), but I'm not getting the scripts to work. `npm run dev` works fine, but `next dev` outputs `zsh: command not found: next`. Why is this?

I'm on macOS 12.5, M1. Node version 16.13.1.

It works when I use the debug tool in VS Code.

`package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "blog-next",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "12.2.5",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "8.22.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.2.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to install the Next cli? https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/cli

Comment: Directly typing `next dev` into a command prompt means the OS has to recognize the `next` command. This will only work if next itself is installed properly, independent of whatever project you have. Till then, `npx next dev` should work

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to install the package globaly(system wide) `npm -g install next`

Comment: I wasn't aware I was supposed to do this? https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/6184#issuecomment-459585264

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't recommend it either. I would just use npm run dev; and avoid all the problems that can come with installing next globally. there can be projects that don't use the same next or react versions in your machine, it's better to keep dependencies isolated. unless it's something like pm2 that manages server I wouldn't install it globally.

but since you asked specifically for it, it doesn't work because it's not installed globally.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this was **caused by running over an outdated Node version** (v.14x).

After upgrading Node everything worked as expected (Dec 2023: v.20x).

Make sense in fact that Nextjs releases requires/compatible with a range of NodeJs versions.

Please, **update your NodeJs version**.

```
# nvm users (node version manager)
nvm use 20

# node users
npm install -g node
npm install -g npm
```