# Command 'next' not found on Ubuntu

Tags: reactjs, ubuntu, next.js

I have created a new next project on my local Ubuntu 20.04 machine using
`npx create-next-app@latest`

I can build and run it using `npm run dev` and `npm run dev`.

I can I also see that I have these in package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
```

But when I run any of the `next ...` commands, I get:

Command 'next' not found, but can be installed with:

```
$ next start

Command 'next' not found, but can be installed with:

apt install mailutils-mh  # version 1:3.7-2.1, or
apt install mmh           # version 0.4-2
apt install nmh           # version 1.7.1-6

Ask your administrator to install one of them
```

My util versions:

```
$node -v 
v16.15.0

$ npm -v
8.5.5

$ npx -v
8.5.5
```

But `next` is not in Ubuntu repos. So I'm wondering how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73386115/15363841) answer, I found the solution. I needed to install `next` globally, like so:

```
pc@ubuntu:~/projects/test-next$ sudo npm -g install next

added 18 packages, and audited 19 packages in 7s

2 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Now I can do:

```
$next start
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
```

Not deleting this answer because I had hard times finding that answer and I think my title is more search-engine friendly. So might help others.